# Flutter - Feedback of Draggable widget does not animate properly

Tags: flutter, animation, draggable, flutter-animation

The AnimatedIcon widget, when holding/dragging it, teleports to the top-left hand of the screen(not intentional). It initially starts at the centre of the screen and returns to same position when it is released. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Note: As this is in GIF format, it does not appear smooth here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HeYZ.gif)

Here's my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
        DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    ]);
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Element(name: 'Fire'),
        )
      )
    );
  }
}

class AnimatedIcon extends AnimatedWidget {

  static final sizeTween = Tween<double>(begin: 80.0, end: 200.0);
  static final marginTween = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 5.0);

  AnimatedIcon({Key key, Animation<double> animation})
      : super(key: key, listenable: animation);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final animation = listenable as Animation<double>;
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: marginTween.evaluate(animation), left: marginTween.evaluate(animation)),
        height: sizeTween.evaluate(animation),
        width: sizeTween.evaluate(animation),

        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }
}


class Element extends StatefulWidget {
  final String name;
  Element({Key key, @required this.name}) : super(key: key);

  ElementState createState() => ElementState();
}

class ElementState extends State<Element> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation<double> animation, animationSize;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 3000), vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Draggable<String>(
      data: widget.name,

      child: AnimatedIcon(animation: controller),
      childWhenDragging: Container(),
      onDragStarted: () => {
        setState(() {
          controller.forward();
        })
      },
      feedback: AnimatedIcon(animation: controller),
      onDragEnd: (details) => {
        setState(() {
          controller.reverse();
        })
      },

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing Center() helped with teleporting

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final animation = listenable as Animation<double>;
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          top: marginTween.evaluate(animation),
          left: marginTween.evaluate(animation)),
      height: sizeTween.evaluate(animation),
      width: sizeTween.evaluate(animation),
      color: Colors.blue,
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Any idea why the Center() widget causes the teleporting?